# OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest PHP equivalent won't print the same result as ruby one

Tags: php, ruby, openssl, base64, hmac

This is a ruby code i need to convert to PHP :

```
print OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha1"), 'hello', Base64.encode64('bonjour'))
```

The output :

> 62ac34e5d28563d6a50272d660805d1f8c791e41

This is my PHP code :

```
echo hash_hmac('sha1', base64_encode('bonjour'), 'hello');
```

The output :

> 89ebf8bd3d92bf3283aa4c5f24072820258367e4

#### I can't found a way to have `62ac34...`.

I tried also :

```
echo hash_hmac('sha1', 'bonjour', 'hello'); // 1
echo hash_hmac('sha1', 'hello', 'bonjour'); // 2
echo hash_hmac('sha1', base64_encode('hello'), 'bonjour'); // 3
echo hash_hmac('sha1', 'hello', base64_encode('bonjour')); // 4
echo base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', 'hello', 'bonjour', TRUE)); //5
```

Which is wrong also. The output :

```
bed443484cc49c41c053a11dd15e44d4f79c524f // 1
16923f8d6e9afd345cf947fc963cad73aa12b76c // 2
8e5989976296c76f0462fe33c6bc2dec48bdcb5a // 3
ca237e79f77e6d9739db45fc5d162da3a4036639 // 4
FpI/jW6a/TRc+Uf8ljytc6oSt2w= // 5
```

I'm totally desperate.

### EDIT

The answer of @Casper doesn't respond completely to my expectation. In case of simple string like `bonjour` there is no problem. But when I put some more complex string, a json string or a longer string (> 60), problems appear.

First of all, following the [Base64 Ruby module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) :

> encode64(bin)
>
> > Returns the Base64-encoded version of bin. This method complies with RFC 2045. Line feeds are added to every 60 encoded characters.

So, in order to have the same base64 encoded data in PHP, I need to insert `\n` every 60 encoded character and also at the end of the string. To do this, PHP provides the [chunk_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) function.

#### Thus, those commands output the same string :

```
chunk_split(base64_encode($json), 60, '\n'); // PHP
Base64.encode64(json) # Ruby
```

#### But it doesn't resolve my problem

The result is still different between PHP and Ruby :

PHP :

```
$json = '{"data":["bonjour"],"id":true,"price":false,"oper":null}';
$base64 = chunk_split(base64_encode($json), 60, '\n');
$hash = hash_hmac('sha1', $base64, 'bonjour');
```

```
// Ouput from var_dump()
eyJkYXRhIjpbImJvbmpvdXIiXSwiaWQiOnRydWUsInByaWNlIjpmYWxzZSwi\nb3BlciI6bnVsbH0=\n // $base64
fd044c309bea13396ed8df47b5c606d950222ceb // $hash
```

Now in Ruby :

```
json_body = '{"data":["bonjour"],"id":true,"price":false,"oper":null}'
encoded_body = Base64.encode64(json_body)
hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha1"), 'bonjour', encoded_body)
```

```
# Ouput from puts var.inspect
eyJkYXRhIjpbImJvbmpvdXIiXSwiaWQiOnRydWUsInByaWNlIjpmYWxzZSwi\nb3BlciI6bnVsbH0=\n # base64
e168f9efe96e9424e22de765c72018c5a3f3437f # hash
```

Notice that `$base64` PHP and `base64` Ruby variable are the same.

What am I doing wrong ? I don't know Ruby, is `puts` and `.inspect` the best way to debug my code ?

Comment: See my updated answer. To debug Ruby variables use `pp` (pretty print). It will usually give you the most information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Ruby is adding newlines to the base64 encoded string, while PHP is not.

Ruby:

```
Base64.encode64('bonjour')
=> "Ym9uam91cg==\n"
```

PHP:

```
base64_encode('bonjour')
=> "Ym9uam91cg=="
```

So now we know how to fix it in PHP:

```
hash_hmac('sha1', base64_encode('bonjour') . "\n", 'hello');
=> "62ac34e5d28563d6a50272d660805d1f8c791e41"
```

Or fixing it in Ruby:

```
OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new("sha1"), 
                        'hello', Base64.encode64('bonjour').chomp)
=> "89ebf8bd3d92bf3283aa4c5f24072820258367e4"
```

#### Part 2

In PHP, as well as in Ruby, `'\n'` is not the same as `"\n"`. The first one produces two characters (`\` followed by `n`), the second one produces a newline.

So to fix your code you need to use newlines, not slash+n, in your strings:

```
$base64 = chunk_split(base64_encode($json), 60, "\n");
                                                ^^^^
```

You could also strip the newlines from the Ruby base64 encoded string with `gsub`, which means you will not need to use any tricks in your PHP code:

```
encoded_body = Base64.encode64(json_body).gsub("\n", '')
```

Comment: Well I did this test and I didn't see `\n`. I should use `var_dump` instead of `echo`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Newlines are easy to miss. I bet you are not the first one to bump into this same issue.

Comment: I've updated my comment. But I still should be more rigorous !

Comment: Please see the update I've just made, it make me crazy !